# How to manipulate joints in a simple legged model

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What's the easiest way to programmatically manipulate a legged model? Through the excellent ["build a robot"](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_robot) tutorial, I was able to build a simple [four-legged](https://github.com/chrisspen/runner/blob/master/research/gazebo/cheetah/models/cheetahbot/model.sdf) platform. How would I manipulating the limbs to test different gaits?

I've read through some of the other tutorials, and I'm a little confused on how to proceed. Do I write a [model plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin), or [connect it to ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros)...or both?

I'm not trying to do anything fancy. I just want to be able to write a simple program to extend/retract/rotate legs in different sequences.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8430/how-to-manipulate-joints-in-a-simple-legged-model/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A model plugin should work for you. Just use [Joint::SetVelocity](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a30b3b4fd789504c9dc265cddb276f3bf) or [Joint::SetForce](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a1eb00145de3a61aaa0ee7506a6ab44c2).

See the [DiffDrivePlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/938eaf5747cee1dce194614a2cbaf91d1a53d145/plugins/DiffDrivePlugin.cc?at=default) for an example.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1